# Invariant of an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, invariants, loop-invariant

Assume this algorithm which gives the maximal sum of a subarray back. And let a[] be an array of length n.

```
randmax = 0
maximum = 0
for 0 <= i < n 
    randmax = randmax + a_i
    if randmax > max 
    max = randmax
    if randmax < 0 
    randmax = 0
```

How can I find a loop invariant, which holds before execution and of course before and after the loop iteration and when n-1 then the invariant should imply the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

If im understanding you're question, then this is what id say:

Initialization: the sum is 0 to start with, so your max is 0

Maintenance: the max so far is the sum of a[0] +...+a[i-1]

Termination: the max is the entire sum of your array a[0] + ... + a[n-1].

So the loop invariant is that the your sum/max at any given time is a[0] + ... + a[i-1], and is only composed of numbers found in your array to begin with.

Comment: Doesn't this assume that all values a_i >= 0 ?

Comment: @Berthur From just the code posted, its just a linear search through the array that adds the keys. If the array were sorted in ascending order then it would only add positive numbers. But, since it doesnt say its sorted, and it goes by 1 every step, it'll add all the keys. Basically, from just the code above, you wouldn't be able to find the max sum of the array without it being sorted first.